# Get position of map area(html)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, maps

Is this possible? I'm trying to find the x and y coordinates of the  element **in relation to the browser**.

```
var position = $(this).position();
    x = position.left;
    y = position.right;
```

Doesn't work.

Is there any way to do this?

<strike>http://adamsaewitz.com/housing/</strike> 
highlight the blue room 070

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Edit for updated question:* Since you're using `<area>` it's a different story, and fetching from the `coords` attribute is much easier, like this:

```
var position = $(this).attr('coords').split(',');
x = +position[0] - 50;
y = +position[1] - 170;
```

The offsets are just to account for the hard-coded width/height of the tooltip itself.  In addition to the above, you want to use `top` and `left` rather than `margin-top` and `margin-left`.  Also to account for the `#content` `<div>`'s position in the page, give it a `relative` position for the tooltip to sit in, like this:

```
#content { position: relative; }
```

Then...instead of [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/), use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) so it gets added *inside* that parent.

[You can test the result here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/YnPsb/6/).

---

*For original question*:
The object [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) returns has `top` and `left` properties...but you want [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) here anyway (it's relative to the *document*, where `.position()` is relative to the *offset parent*), so it should look like this:

```
var position = $(this).offset(),
    x = position.left,
    y = position.top; //not right!
```

Or this:

```
var position = $(this).offset();
var x = position.left;
var y = position.top;
```

...but without a single `var` comma-separated statement, or a `var` on each line, you're also creating (or trying to) global variables, which will blow up in IE.

Comment: Strange use of the comma operator.

Comment: Haha, wow that's a sign it's late. But that still doesn't work, sorry.

Comment: @Switz - what's not working?  Note you want `.offset()` not `.position()`, which is relative to the *parent*, not the `document`.

Comment: I'm using global operators. The instances are created earlier.

Comment: @Tomas - how so? it's just a single `var` declaration, standard JS :)

Comment: I've posted the example up in the main post, please take a look at the code.

Comment: @Switz - one sec, taking a look

Comment: @Switz - have you considered grabbing it from the `coords` attribute you already have, like this? http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/YnPsb/

Comment: Yes, but then if the window is not the size of the image, it doesn't line up properly.  I'm sure there's a way to get around it, but I wanted to avoid it. I have an idea. gimmie a sec, thanks

Comment: @Switz - if you insert the content in a relative parent that contains both...the image//window relation doesn't matter, since it's in relation to the area that contains the image, if you notice I changed it to `.append()` rather than `.after()` when creating the tooltip.

Comment: I did that and it's still not working. Updated jsfiddle: http://www.jsfiddle.net/YnPsb/2/  if you resize the browser it changes its location, idk why.

Comment: @Switz, This should work as you want it .. http://www.jsfiddle.net/YnPsb/5/ You need to get the info from the coords, but at the same time adjust for the image (*they point to*) offset. Additionally you need to adjust for the width/height of the info box as well as the area width.

Comment: That looks great! Very intuitive.  Make it an answer and I'll give you credit. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Switz - you just need to give `#content` that  relative position I mentioned in the last comment: `#content { position: relative; }`, check it out here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/YnPsb/6/

Answer (score 7):

The problem lies in the fact that you are accessing the top/left of an area element.

The area element is not positioned where its coords say. This is handled behind the scenes by the dom/browser.

So you need to find the image that the `area` relates to and grab its offset.

```
var imgId = $(this).closest('map').attr('name');
var imgPos = $('#' + imgId).offset();
```

Then, you grab the `coords` attribute  of the `area` and split it to get `left`/`top`/`width` and use those to pinpoint the location inside the image.

```
var coords = $(this).attr('coords').split(',');
var box = {
            left: parseInt(coords[0],10),
            top: parseInt(coords[1],10),
            width:  parseInt(coords[2],10)-parseInt(coords[0],10),
            height:  parseInt(coords[3],10)-parseInt(coords[1],10)
            };
```

Take into consideration the width/height of the info box that appears (*and since you animate it, take that into consideration as well*) and you get to

```
x = imgPos.left + box.left + box.width/2 - 65; // 65 is the info width/2
y = imgPos.top + box.top -20 -160 -1; // 20 is the animation, 160 is the info height, 1 is a safe distance from the top
```

**demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/XBjwN/

Comment: There's no need for the overhead here, just giving the parent a `relative` position takes care of the offset in a much cleaner way, see the comments on my answer for links to demos of this.

Comment: Good point @Nick. In the present case, the relative `#content` indeed solves the issue. But if there was any other content inside the `#content` (*and the name implies there might be*) and before the image it would not. Same goes for the map object to be defined somewhere else..

Comment: true, valid concerns, but I'd *still* go for the `relative` option, if a `<div class="areaWrapper">` is needed around each then I still find it a much cleaner/more versatile approach, as you have a consistent `.closest()` accessibly parent to put your elements in as well.

Comment: @nick, agreed! It is cleaner your way. (*the `map` used in the `.closest()`, though, is obligatory for the area elements*)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('map').imageMapResize();
            $('area').hover(function () {
                $('.imgpopover').css({ "display": "block", "top": $(this).attr("coords").split(',')[1]+"px", "left": $(this).attr("coords").split(',')[0]+"px" })
                $('.imgpopover label').text($(this).attr("title"))
            }, )
        });
```