# position div at mouse for specific usemap elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, position, imagemap

I need to position a div on an img using a usemap.

Only when the mouse hovers over a specific area, the div would appear - exactly at that mouse position.

I have found a few examples with jquery the sorts of

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $("#mydiv").mouseover(function(e){
      $('#showDiv').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
   });
})
```

but this calls my div always; I'd like to show it only when it hovers over specific area elements. (Hope I was clear?).Thanks

Comment: I think I found what I was looking for here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529957/get-position-of-map-areahtml

Answer (score 0):

Hide the div on [`mouseout()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) and upon page ready.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#showDiv').hide();

    $("#mydiv").mouseover(function(e){
       $('#showDiv').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
       $('#showDiv').show()
    });

    $('#mydiv').mouseout(function() {
        $('#showDiv').hide();
    });
})
```

Comment: I think you need to show the div in your `mouseover`: `$('#showDiv').show()`

Comment: Ok, but this will show my div anywhere on the img. I want it to appear only when hovering over specific areas of the imagemap, not when hovering over the whole imagemap.

Comment: In other words what I need is a mouseover over an <area> which would then pop up a div right at that <area> and disappear when I leave that <area>

Comment: Ah, yeah, I'm afraid that kind of question is too general for me to help you there. However, if you have a more specific question once you start implementing it, I'm sure somebody could help you out.